# Color blending (multiply) for matplotlib pcolormesh overlay

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm trying to overlay two sets of arrays with values between 0,1 with matplotlib pcolormesh. This is no problem doing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.colors as colors
%matplotlib inline

array1 = np.random.random([20,20])
array2 = np.random.random([20,20])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolormesh(array1, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, alpha=0.5)
heatmap2 = ax.pcolormesh(array2, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.5)
```

The result is correctly blended, except that the dynamic range is split in two (we cannot get full red or full blue values when one is high (close to 1) and the other is 0, as the alpha blending makes everything a little more dull).

What i'm after is similar to a multiplication of the color: values close to [1, 0] should be full red, values close to [0, 1] should be full blue, values close to [1, 1] full magenta and values close to [0, 0] white.

Is is possible to have such a 2D colormap?

Right now I can do it in Photoshop 'multiply' blend, but I need a Python solution

Comment: do u want the output to be like this http://imgur.com/VNeins2

Comment: I am using your own data, but I am not able to understand what you are expecting the output to be

Comment: I expect the plot I gave the code for, but with higher saturation; the alpha removes saturation from the 'pure' red and blues as well as the blended purple.

Comment: Erm, wouldn't [0,0] be normally be black?